# Windows: Install node and then in same .ps1 script npm packages get error "npm" not recognized

Tags: node.js, powershell, cmd, vagrant-windows

First time that work with Windows and Vagrant, and I trying to create Windows server 2016 Vagrant box with pre-installed chocolatey, nodejs and npm packages. Here is the script choco.ps1:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope Process -Force; iex ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))
choco install -y nodejs --version 4.9.1
refreshenv
npm install windows-build-tools@2 -g
```

Chocolatey and node successfully installed, but when trying to install something with npm get error of '"npm" not recognized as internal or external command'.

When connecting to vagrant box i see that node and npm installed, but looks like I can't in same script install node and npm, and run "npm install".
I even found that command "refreshenv" should help, but it not...

Any suggestions how can install npm packages after installing node?

Answer (score 1):

After installing node you also need to install/update for more information follow this steps [Click Here!](https://nodesource.com/blog/installing-nodejs-tutorial-windows/) see step no. 4

Comment: No, after "choco install nodejs" you don't need all this steps